# How to add linear-gradient color to Material UI Chip background?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to add linear-gradient below color to Material UI `Chip` as a background color. Is it possible?

```css
linear-gradient(to right bottom, #430089, #82ffa1)
```

I am using Material UI v0.18.7.

```
<Chip backgroundColor={indigo400} style={{width: 120}}>
     <Avatar size={32} color={white} backgroundColor={indigo900}>A</Avatar>
     This is a Chip
</Chip>
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just set the `background` to the desired gradient in your styles:

```
<Chip style={{width: 120, background: 'linear-gradient(to right bottom, #430089, #82ffa1)'}}>
     <Avatar size={32} color={white} backgroundColor={indigo900}>A</Avatar>
     This is a Chip
</Chip>
```

Note that `linear-gradient` is a CSS function that returns an image, not a color. So, you have to set the `background` property (which takes an image) rather than the `backgroundColor` property (which takes just a color). Here's a quote [from the Mozilla docs explaining this more thoroughly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient):

> Because `<gradient>`s belong to the `<image>` data type, they can only be used where `<image>`s can be used. For this reason, `linear-gradient()` won't work on `background-color` and other properties that use the `<color>` data type.

Comment: Great Jules! Silly one I should've tried on my own. Thank you :)

Comment: Glad I could help, Hemadri! Always a pleasure.

Answer (score 6):

You can override any component in material-ui using classes. 
Instead of backgroundColor try this code.

```js
//After imports statements
const style={
  chip:{
    background: 'linear-gradient(to right bottom, #430089, #82ffa1)',
  }
}
class Chips extends ...{
  render(){
const classes=this.props.classes;
  return(
    <Chip className={classes.chip}>
      <!--Content-->
     </Chip>
  );
  }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 6):

In **Material UI v5**, you can use either [`sx`](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/) or [`styled()`](https://mui.com/system/styled/):

##### **`sx`** prop

```
<Chip
  label="Chip Filled"
  sx={{
    color: 'white',
    background: 'linear-gradient(to right bottom, #36EAEF, #6B0AC9)',
  }}
/>
```

##### `styled()`

```
type GradientChipProps = {
  colors?: string[];
};
const GradientChip = styled(Chip)<GradientChipProps>(({ colors }) => ({
  color: 'white',
  ...(colors && {
    background: `linear-gradient(to right bottom, ${colors.join(',')})`,
  }),
}));
```

```
<GradientChip
  label="Chip Outlined"
  variant="outlined"
  colors={['red', 'pink', 'purple']}
/>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

### Related Answer

- [Gradient border on Material UI component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66996114/9449426)