# Can I create a gradient background color on a material Chip?

Tags: android, kotlin, material-components, material-components-android, android-chips

I believe the answer is yes as I can see this answer for react [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48849340/how-to-add-linear-gradient-color-to-material-ui-chip-background), but I don't know how to do it in Kotlin/Java.
The only to options I see are `setChipBackgroundColorResource` or `setBackgroundColor` which both require a color resource. How can I use gradient for the background?

- I know how to set backgrounds for any regular view, but having an issue just with the chip. I've tried this `chip.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gradient_background)` but it just makes the background gray

Comment: @AdarshAnurag not really a duplicate..

Answer (score 3):

Currently you **can't do** it.

- The method `setChipBackgroundColorResource` is working with a `color` not a `drawable`
- The method `setChipBackgroundColor` is working with a `ColorStateList`
- The [methods](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/chip/Chip.java#L497) `setBackgroundResource`, `setBackgroundDrawable`, `setBackground` just produce a warning:`Do not set the background; Chip manages its own background drawable.`

It happens because the Chip widget is a thin view wrapper around the [`ChipDrawable`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/chip/ChipDrawable.java). The ChipDrawable is just a `MaterialShapeDrawable` whick manages its background with something like:

```
 *   chipStartPadding     iconEndPadding     closeIconStartPadding         chipEndPadding
 *    +                    +                                    +                      +
 *    |                    |                                    |                      |
 *    |  iconStartPadding  |  textStartPadding   textEndPadding | closeIconEndPadding  |
 *    |   +                |    +                            +  |                  +   |
 *    |   |                |    |                            |  |                  |   |
 *    v   v                v    v                            v  v                  v   v
 * +-----+----+-----------+----+----+---------------------+----+----+----------+----+-----+
 * |     |    |       XX  |    |    |  XX   X  X  X  XXX  |    |    | X      X |    |     |
 * |     |    |      XX   |    |    | X  X  X  X  X  X  X |    |    |  XX  XX  |    |     |
 * |     |    |  XX XX    |    |    | X     XXXX  X  XXX  |    |    |    XX    |    |     |
 * |     |    |   XXX     |    |    | X  X  X  X  X  X    |    |    |  XX  XX  |    |     |
 * |     |    |    X      |    |    |  XX   X  X  X  X    |    |    | X      X |    |     |
 * +-----+----+-----------+----+----+---------------------+----+----+----------+----+-----+
 *                  ^                           ^                         ^
 *                  |                           |                         |
 *                  +                           +                         +
 *             chipIconSize                  *dynamic*              closeIconSize
 *
```

Comment: Did that maybe change since then?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to set a background to Chip rather you can set the rounded corners or colors to it. You can also give a border color.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/chip/Chip),

> All attributes from Chip are supported. Do not use the
>   android:background attribute. It will be ignored because Chip manages
>   its own background Drawable. Also do not use the android:drawableStart
>   and android:drawableEnd attributes.

Hence if you are looking something to give corners or a chip with a different border color I would suggest you to try this,

```
    Chip chip = new Chip(Activity.this);
    chip.setText("Holiday");
    chip.setCloseIcon(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.close_chip, null));
    chip.setCloseIconTint(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#aa99bc")));
    chip.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);  
    chip.setCloseIconVisible(true);
    chip.setTextAppearanceResource(R.style.ChipTextStyle);
    chip.setChipStrokeColorResource(R.color.chip_border_color);
    chip.setChipStrokeWidth(1);
    chip.setChipCornerRadius(30);                                          
    chip.setChipBackgroundColorResource(R.color.chip_background);
```