# Gradient border on MUI component

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jss, makestyles

I did not manage to find the equivalent of `border-image-source` css

My goal is to render a border gradient on a button component

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how you add a gradient border to the `button` component:

#### V5

```
const options = {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'gradientColors',
};

const GradientButton = styled(
  Button,
  options,
)(({ theme, gradientColors }) => ({
  border: '5px solid',
  borderImageSlice: 1,
  borderImageSource: `linear-gradient(to left, ${gradientColors.join(',')})`,
}));
```

If you want a round button with gradient border, you can't use the code above since `borderImage` [doesn't have a radius](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5707228/9449426). A workaround is to create a gradient background in the child element `:after` because the `background` can be clipped using `borderRadius`:

```
const borderRadius = 15;
const RoundGradientButton = styled(
  Button,
  options,
)(({ theme, gradientColors }) => ({
  position: 'relative',
  border: '5px solid transparent',
  backgroundClip: 'padding-box',
  borderRadius,

  '&:after': {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: -5,
    left: -5,
    right: -5,
    bottom: -5,
    background: `linear-gradient(to left, ${gradientColors.join(',')})`,
    content: '""',
    zIndex: -1,
    borderRadius,
  },
}));
```

##### Usage

```
<GradientButton gradientColors={['red', 'yellow']} variant="contained">
  Default
</GradientButton>
<RoundGradientButton gradientColors={['red', 'yellow']} variant="contained">
  Default
</RoundGradientButton>
```

##### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

#### V4

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
  button: {
    border: "6px solid",
    borderImageSlice: 1,
    borderImageSource: "linear-gradient(to left, red, orange)"
  }
}));

export default function ContainedButtons() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Button className={classes.button} variant="contained">
      Default
    </Button>
  );
}
```

##### Live Demo

[image: Edit 66995679/gradient-border-on-component-material-ui]

#### Related Answer

- [How to add linear-gradient color to MUI Chip background?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69799194/9449426)

Comment: May you know how to add border radius ? Because borderRadius isnt working with borderImageSource

Comment: @seserize See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29223812/9449426) answer, I've updated the live demo for you.